# Вставка изображений перед блочным элементом css3 (варианты и особенности)

Tags: css, css3

В чем разница вставки изображений перед содержанием блочного элемента с помощью свойства "background-image" и "padding-left" с помощью псевдокласса "before"?

Предположим, что необходимо вставить изображение именно слева, допустим глазик перед количеством просмотров.
Мне интересны достоинства и недостатки каждого из методов, а также возможные особенности их реализации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все зависит от конкретной ситуации и результата, который вам нужен. Оба методы могут быть хороши для отдельных случаев.

Ключевое различие в том, что с использованием **before** картинка вставляется инлайново и полностью зависит от контента, так как является его частью.

В случае с **background** картинка лежит в фоне и вы можете позиционировать ее как угодно в рамках контейнера. Бонусом идет то, что если вы скопируете несколько таких элементов выделением, то скопируется только текст, что очень удобно для вставки.

Другой случай: если текст справа от иконки может занять несколько строк, то в случае с **before** он залезет под иконку на второй строке. В случае с **background** сдвигается весь контент, так что текст на последующих строках также будет выровнен.

Пример:

```css
p { width: 200px; }

.img-before:before {
  content:url(https://placekitten.com/g/20/20);
}

.img-bg {
  padding-left: 30px;
  background: url(https://placekitten.com/g/20/20) left top no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<p class="img-before">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

<p class="img-bg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

Comment: Предлагаю ещё before c float'ом в ответ добавить.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, картинку c помощью "before:" также можно позиционировать относительно блока "обертки контента" через "position: absolute;"

Comment: Можно, но для этого нужно описывать ее позиционирование дополнительными свойствами, назначать relative родителю и она все еще будет "копироваться". Плюс и контент тогда придется двигать также дополнительно, ведь сама картинка с absolute больше не будет его сдвигать. В итоге получится очень громоздкий код. Но повторюсь, все зависит от ваших потребностей.